# docker container (node server) stops with err=132

Tags: node.js, docker, synology

my first docker project was built on a Mac.
It runs perfectly there, so I tried to transfer that to my Synology NAS running in the docker engine there.
Unfortunately, the container always stops with Error Code = 132.
I tried everything, pulling from within the docker GUI and running the container from there, but also directly from the cli (ssh). Always the same!
Any Idea?
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine
USER node
WORKDIR /home/node
ADD --chown=node:node . /home/node
RUN npm install
CMD ["node","myApp.js"]
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?  Is it possible you built the image on an ARM (M1) Mac but are trying to run it on an x86 system, or _vice versa_?

Comment: I used a x86 Mac but to my understanding is docker always running under it's own (small) linux OS.
The code is an exit code = 132.